# istio setting request size limits - lookup failed: 'request.size'

Tags: istio

I am attempting to limit traffic by request size using istio.  Given that the virtual service does not provide this I am trying to due it via a mixer policy.

I setup the following

```
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: denylargerequest
spec:
  compiledAdapter: denier
  params:
    status:
      code: 9
      message: Request Too Large
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: denylargerequest
spec:
  compiledTemplate: checknothing
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: denylargerequest
spec:
  match: destination.labels["app"] == "httpbin" && request.size > 100
  actions:
    - handler: denylargerequest
      instances: [ denylargerequest ]
```

Requests are not denied and I see the following error from istio-mixer

```
2020-01-07T15:42:40.564240Z warn    input set condition evaluation error: id='2', error='lookup failed: 'request.size''
```

If I remove the request.size portion of the match I get the expected behavior which is a 400 http status with a message about request size.  Of course, I get it on every request which is not desired.  But that, along with the above error makes it clear that the request.size attribute is the problem.

I do not see anywhere in istio's docs what attributes are available to the mixer rules.

I am running istio 1.3.0.

Any suggestions on the mixer rule?  Or an alternative way to enforce request size limits via istio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule match mentioned in the question:

```
match: destination.labels["app"] == "httpbin" && request.size > 100
```

will not work because of mismatched attribute types.

According to istio documentation:

> Match is an attribute based predicate. When Mixer receives a request
>   it evaluates the match expression and executes all the associated 
>   `actions`  if the match evaluates to true.
>
> A few example match:
>
> - an empty match evaluates to  `true`
> - `true`, a boolean literal; a rule with this match will always be executed
> - `match(destination.service.host, "ratings.*")`  selects any request targeting a service whose name starts with “ratings”
> - `attr1 == "20" && attr2 == "30"`  logical AND, OR, and NOT are also available

This means that the `request.size > 100` has integer values that are not supported.

---

However, it is possible to do with help of **Common Expression Language**  ([CEL](https://github.com/google/cel-spec)).

You can enable CEL in istio by using the  `policy.istio.io/lang`  annotation (set it to  `CEL`).

Then by using  [Type Values](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#type-values)  from the  [List of Standard Definitions](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#list-of-standard-definitions)  we can use functions to parse values into different types.

Just as a suggesion for solution.

---

Alternative way would be to use envoyfilter filter like in this [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13719) issue.

According to another related [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15260) issue about Envoy's per connection buffer limit:

> The current resolution is to use envoyfilter, reopen if you feel this is a must feature

Hope this helps.

Comment: For my current use case, I plan to recommend that we accept that we cannot limit request size via istio and mitigate some other way or accept it as a risk.  

1) envoy filter equals code in yaml, yuk and likely fragile over time
2) CEL has promise but I do not have time now to explore using it to both do the arithmetic > evaluation and then transform that result into a string.  I feel that if I have to do so much to make something possible then I am likely not using the right tool 

but your I believe your answer is correct for istio and request size 

thank you